# Difference between print(*) and *.print()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was staring at a very very long code. I am just trying the GUI part. There were these lines :

```
        sh = packing_options[best_index].sheets[idx]
        sh.print()
        for rect in sh.rect_list:
            rect.print()
```

I wanted to show the value stored in sh and rect for the GUI window.

When I use

```
b3 = tk.Label(top, text=sh)
b3.grid(row=0, column=2) 

b4 = tk.Label(top, text=rect)
b4.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

It gives this as the result : <**main**.Sheet object at 0x0000024F5CF4A320>

The code for classes are given below:

```
class Rect:
    def __init__(self, w, l):
        self.l = l
        self.w = w

    def print(self):
        print('Rect w:' + str(self.w) + 'l:' + str(self.l))

    def area(self):
        return self.l * self.w

## class for sheet to save all rectangles' positions
class Sheet:

    # initialization
    def __init__(self, W, L):
        self.W = W             # width (=horizontal length)
        self.L = L             # length (=height, vertical length)
        self.rect_list = []    # rectangle list
        self.rect_pos = []     # rectangle starting position from left bottom 
        self.rect_rotate = []  # rectangle rotation indicator list, 0: not rotated, 1: rotated
        self.lhl_x = [0,W]     # lowest horizontal line boundary point list
        self.lhl_y = [0]       # lowest horizontal line height list: each element is height

    # area of sheet
    def area(self):
        return self.L * self.W

    def print(self):
        print('sheet W:' + str(self.W) + ' L:' + str(self.L))
```

How do I get the real value and store it in a variable to use print(*) (To use to show in GUI ultimately)

Comment: `.print` is a tkinter object function, `print` is a python function.

Comment: Looks like `Sheet` is a class defined in the file you were reading and `sh` is an instance of that class. Said class has a method `print()` defined and line `sh.print()` calls method `Sheet.print()` of class `Sheet` , while `print(*)` is a standard python function that attempts to print to console whatever you give it as an argument, but since `Sheet` is a custom class it doesn't know what the proper text representation is, so it prints the name of the class the object belongs to and its memory address as this is the default behavior.

Comment: @IcedLance Can we store that value for viewing in the GUI?

Comment: @devinxxxd yes.

Comment: @IcedLance How can it be done?

Comment: @devinxxxd you didn't share the code so i have no idea. Sheet is a custom class, not part of `tkinter`, the only ones who know what it is are you and the person who wrote it.

Comment: @IcedLance I have added the class here, please check it

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as the behaviour of Python to `print` ing the object of a regular `class` , I.e if you provide the `__str__` method it will print the object in stringified form with detail you are looking for (ofcourse you decide what is going to be printed) but if there is no `__str__` method in the class, then printing an object will give you a queer output including address location of the object (similar to your example ) as standard `print` method does not know printing an object.

```
<__main__.Foobar instance at 0x7cf2a22e>
```

`print(sh)` is doing the same thing (nothing unexpected).

For this particular question both the `print` s are different `.print` is *tkinter* method defined on `sh`  and print is *python's* method.

If you want to use the `sh`  in *python's* built-in `print` function then you need to have a `__str__` (or `__repr__`) method in the *class* *Sheet* , which will be the string representation of your object, because `print(sh)` finally invokes `Sheet.__str__()`:

And in that `__str__` method you can simply put all the details you wish to see on screen using the `self` keyword.

Very simple example in this direction will be

```
def __str__(self):
     print('sheet W:' + str(self.W) + ' L:' + str(self.L))
```

`__str__` is the string representation of an object and better think of it as `toString` function in *Java* (if you are familiar with it)

Comment: I have edited my question and added the class sheet and rect. Can you check it ?

Comment: @devinxxxd see if you can get something from the above solution, do let me know what else you want to know

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import enumerate
from tkinter import messagebox

def sheet_info(sheet):
   str = "Sheet W:{} L:{} Contains {} rectangles:".format(sheet.W, sheet.L, len(sheet.rect_list))
   for idx, rect in enumerate(sheet.rect_list):
      str += "\n   Rectangle W:{} L:{} at position {}".format(rect.w, rect.l, sheet.rect_pos[idx])
   return str

messagebox.showinfo("sheet info", sheet_info(sh))
```

This should do it. May contain mistakes as i can't verify it atm.

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showinfo("Title", "your text here")
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: The text of the question has been changed. This is the answer to the question of how to get the text on screen in GUI window.

Comment: @HenryYik Can you tell me the way to show the value in tkinter GUI?

Comment: @devinxxx revert to original question and past your update below it as and with label "update". Otherwise it makes Ramil's answer looks silly. In return Ramil could update his/her answer as well once you included the update correctly. Cheers in advance for the adjustment. (From Review).